# Set a cell of a datagrid to a specific text

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

I have a datagrid with an ArrayCollection as dataProvider. i want change the value displayed in a specific cell to another value.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Shall I change the value in the arrayCollection itself?

Thanks to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Change the value in the ArrayCollection and the DataGrid should update.

Comment: But how do I change it for a specific column in a specific row?